# Best performance for mySQL and PHP: Lots of small queries, or a large one?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So i have this technicall dilemma:

I have a Wordpress site, with more than 50 categories (and rising). I want to get just the six categories with the newest article in them, and -if i get this right- i can't do it with a single typical WP Query, i'll have to improvise:

a) get from the database the last 200-300 posts, and by elimination in PHP filter by category, and show the six last updated categories, or

b) get from the database all my categories, and for each category ask again the database the last article by date - and show the six last updated categories.

i know that the first solution is not very safe, and will strech a little my server calculating with PHP, but the second will have more than 50+1 queries (and rising).

Considering that the site i'm working on has a couple of million visitors each month, which one do you think will give, from a technical point of view, the less stress to my servers?

Or i'm missing an more obvius solution?

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you post something, you could save the taxonomy's `name`/`slug`/`id` in a [transient](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/) on publishing/updating through [`set_transient()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_transient/) and [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) action hook.

Saving the data as an array and [slicing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) it once it reach 6... [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) before updating...

To display them you would simply loop through the transient's value and [`get_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy/) or build a custom [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) looping through each of them.

Which would avoid you a lot of queries. Pretty much none...

here is an untested demo:

```php
<?php

//Retieve the transient through get_transient( '_transient_wpso_73900689' );
add_action( 'save_post', function ( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {

    $transient = '_transient_wpso_73900689';

    $expiration = 0;

    $prev_value  = ! empty( get_transient( $transient ) ) ? get_transient( $transient ) : array();

    $next_value = get_post_taxonomies( $post_ID );

    $buffer = array();

    if ( ! empty( $next_value ) ) {

        foreach ( $next_value as $taxonomy ) {

            //Search the previous transient array.
            if ( array_search( $taxonomy, $prev_value ) === false ) {
    
                //If the value doesn't exist, push the value to the array.
                array_push( $buffer, $taxonomy );

            };

        };

        $value = array_merge( $prev_value, $buffer );

        //Reverse the array.
        $value = array_reverse( $value );

        //Retrieve the last 6.
        $value = array_slice( $value, 0, 6 );

        //Set the transient.
        set_transient( $transient, $value, 0 );

    };

}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: That is an innovative idea! I will certainly consider it. Thanks!

Comment: Wait ! I'm writing something more in depth, give me a few minutes ! Great question by the way !

Comment: Just updated the post with a basic demo, hope it helps.

Comment: You can also save the query result into a transient on first request, then serve from transient, and delete the transient on saving a new post

Answer (score 1):

Can,t you just join the articles and sort by the joined table ordered by date desc?

Something like:
Select from categories c
Left join articles a on a.category = c.id
Order by a.date desc group by c.id limit 6

Comment: Thank you, yes, i could ask the query in plain MySQL, and i'm considering it as a legit and clean solution. But the question is more theoretical, witch of the two is more proccess consuming for my database and server :)

Comment: Ah okay, then I would guess the second approach would consume more time. 

Selecting 200 rows in approach A will be no problem and the php can stop as soon it found 6 different categories which will probably be after the first 20 rows?